# Make template pluggable in Django

Tags: python, django

Let say I'm writting an app "Profile" ; I have the following template (in profile/presentation.html):

```
<h1>{{user.first_name}}<h1>
<p> This user likes {{user.hobby}}</p>
```

Which is attached to a view :

```
# profile/views.py
class DetailUserView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'members/profile_detail.html'
# profile/urls.py
urlpatterns = ( url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.DetailPersonView.as_view(), name='profile'))
# project/urls.py
urlpatterns = ( .., url(r'^profile/', include(profile.urls), ...)
```

Now I would like to "plug" this template in my project layout:

```
<!-- project/templates/project/layout.html-->
<html>
 <head>
   <title>My Site</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>The title !!</header>
    {%block body_block%}{%endblock%}
 </body>
</html>
```

If I want to keep uncoupled my app, I can't inherit "presentation.hmtl" from "layout.html".

How can I say to django: when we ask /profile/2, take the result of the view "DetailUserView" and plug it in the layout at the "body_block"?

Comment: the [`include` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). The docs have a lot of good information.

## project/templates/project/layout.html

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>My Site</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>The title !!</header>
    {%block body_block%}{%endblock%}
 </body>
</html>
```

## project/templates/profile/presentation.html

```
{% extends "project/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>{{user.first_name}}<h1>
    <p> This user likes {{user.hobby}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This way, the application profile depends on the specific project i'm working on, and I want to be able to use the Profile app and templates in several projects.

Comment: Then you need to create a third party library and install it like you would any other library from PyPI.